# Defining implicit format for Enumeration objects via trait in Scala

Tags: scala, object, inheritance, enums, traits

I am attempting to define an implicit trait for multiple objects to be used when de-serializing JSON values for Enumerations. I understand how to do this within an object, but I was hoping to template this behavior to keep my code DRY. I can accomplish this by doing something like:

```
object SomeEnum extends Enumeration {
  type SomeEnum = Value
  val FIRST: SomeEnum = Value("First")
  val SECOND: SomeEnum = Value("Second")
  implicit object SomeEnumFormat extends Format[SomeEnum] {
    def writes(o: SomeEnum): JsValue = JsString(o.toString)

    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[SomeEnum] = json match {
      case JsString(x) => JsSuccess(SomeEnum.withName(x.toLowerCase.capitalize))
      case _ => JsError()
    }
  }
}
```

Below is what I have been attempting:

```
object SomeEnum extends Mappable {
  val FIRST: SomeEnum = Value("First")
  val SECOND: SomeEnum = Value("Second")
}

object SomeOtherEnum extends Mappable {
  val ABC: SomeOtherEnum = Value("Abc")
  val DEF: SomeOtherEnum = Value("Def")
}

trait Mappable extends Enumeration {
  implicit val enumMapper: JdbcType[Value] with BaseTypedType[Value] = MappedColumnType.base[Value,String](_.toString, this.withName)

  def unapply[Type](s: String): Option[Value] = values.find(s == _.toString)

  implicit object someFormat extends Format[Class[_ <: Mappable]] {
    def writes(o: Class[_ <: Mappable]): JsValue = JsString(o.toString)

    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Value] = json match {
      case JsString(x) => JsSuccess(this.asInstanceOf[Mappable].withName(x.toLowerCase.capitalize))
      case _ => JsError()
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect that the inherited trait would have acted the same way a providing a template version of the implicit object for the class extending the trait, but instead I am getting the following error:

```
found   : Mappable#Value
required: Mappable.this.Value
```

If I put the return type of read to `JsResult[Mappable#Value]` The code does not compile because no implicit declaration is found for the specified enumeration type. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially misunderstood what was happening, and the following was the solution which worked

```scala
object SomeEnum extends Mappable {
  type SomeEnum = Value
  val FIRST: SomeEnum = Value("First")
  val SECOND: SomeEnum = Value("Second")
}

object SomeOtherEnum extends Mappable {
  type SomeOtherEnum = Value
  val ABC: SomeOtherEnum = Value("Abc")
  val DEF: SomeOtherEnum = Value("Def")
}

trait Mappable extends Enumeration {
  implicit val enumMapper: JdbcType[Value] with BaseTypedType[Value] = MappedColumnType.base[Value,String](_.toString, this.withName)

  def unapply[Type](s: String): Option[Value] = values.find(s == _.toString)

  implicit object someFormat extends Format[Value] {
    def writes(o: Value): JsValue = JsString(o.toString)

    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Value] = json match {
      case JsString(x) => JsSuccess(withName(x.toLowerCase.capitalize))
      case _ => JsError()
    }
  }
}
```